# Incorrect code for 2-dimensional array of int and double

Tags: c#, arrays

I've received some code from someone that I don't completely understand, but doesn't look at all correct to me. Although this code seems to work in a C# console application that tests it, I am unable to get it to work in a C# web application.

I've never used a comma to declare a two dimensional array in this manner. I don't see any way that this array is reliable to contain `int` values. At the very least it looks like a 2-dimensional array of nothing but doubles.

The code here has been slightly modified (shortened) for brevity. Each of the whole numbers below are ***suppose*** to be `int` values. I can understand how the decimal numbers are doubles, but not the whole numbers being ints.

```
double[,] SomeData = new double[,] {
    {0,1,2.4,494,15314.03063,4,10.6,0.15,0},
    {1,1,2.4,476,14756.02951,6,10.6,0.15,0},
    {2,1,3.7,577,17887.03577,4,10.6,0.15,0}
}
```

Isn't this coding convention incorrect and/or unreliable? Can anyone provide an example of how this array should be declared?

Comment: So you are asking how an int can be a double?

Comment: It's perfectly legal. The integers are automatically converted to doubles by the compiler.

Comment: Here is a simple example: `double d = 5.0; int i = 5; bool b = d == i;//true`

Comment: Yes, it's a 2d array of doubles. Says so right there: `new double[,]`. If you assign an int32 literal to a double, it gets cast implicitly, because there's no loss of information. Actually, for all I know the compiler may be promoting those to double literals. Might look that up. I don't know what you mean by "unreliable"; it'll behave the same way every time you run it, I promise.

Comment: No, I understand that an int can be a double 1 = 1.0 for sure. But each type has a different length. The data is used later on in the code to populate integers and doubles.

Comment: It's storing doubles. Casting them to ints later will require an explicit cast.

Comment: Internally, each element of the jagged array is typed double, so they are all allocated the same amount of space. For example, using two doubles, `1` takes up as much space as `13.342536` as they are both typed as double.

Comment: @TravisJ It's not a jagged array. If it was, it would have been declared as `double[][]`.

Comment: @EdPlunkett And if they are not cast explicitly to `int` could this cause a `System.AccessViolationException`? I think the array should be an array of `struct`. I just wouldn't have done it the way it was done but I don't want to challenge the author without researching and I'm not finding an explanation about this.

Comment: @rwkiii Access violation? No, it just won't compile.

Comment: @EdPlunkett It's just not my style and I'm trying to track down a problem. The code works from a test console application, but I'm stumped as to why it is bombing out in the web app. I see what you are saying - in itself it is 'ok'. I probably have not located the code that is tripping the Access Violation. The code above is inside a C# DLL that calls a C++ DLL that calls another C++ DLL and something is causing: `Access Violation.Unhandled Exception: System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.`

Comment: If you're certain that it's the DLL throwing the exception (the stack trace on the exception ought to identify the origin), you might get a lot closer by posting the pinvoke declaration of the DLL function and all you can about what's being passed into it and how it's called

Comment: If you're lucky it could be as simple as some int being passed in as a pointer, but it's just arbitrary crap.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I won't hammer this to death. I realize I didn't document this completely, but... my C# web app is calling a C# DLL that in turn calls a C++ DLL. The exception is being thrown from the C# DLL I call. I will troubleshoot further. Thank you for lending some clarification - you did actually help (except for one of your comments).

Comment: @EdPlunkett I checked the signatures and they look correct.